# Initializing arrays when using templates

Tags: c++, class, gcc, g++, c++11

Let's say I have the class `Foo`. The following works fine:

```
class Foo
{
    public:
        const int* bar;

        Foo()
        {
            bar = new int[2] {1, 2};
        }
};
```

However, I tried to change this very slightly to use a template:

```
template<int A, int B>
class Foo
{
    public:
        const int* bar;

        Foo()
        {
            bar = new int[2] {A, B};
        }
};
```

My understanding of the way templates work is that `A` and `B` are essentially compile time constants, so it should still work the same.

The error message I get when compiling [with g++](http://ideone.com/h7K7y) (4.5 in the link, same error with 4.6.3) is:

> error: ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new [-fpermissive]

[With 4.7](http://pastie.org/3679616) a similar error occurs, though slightly different:

> error: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]

The problem also occurs in template functions, and not just when template parameters are used within the braces for initialization, [code and output](https://gist.github.com/2220810). (thanks Philipp)

Comment: Are you compiling in C++11 mode?

Comment: http://ideone.com/h7K7y  Interesting.

Comment: I was compiling with `-std=c++0x` in both cases. The result from Mooing Duck is exactly as i got (i mistake a look at ideone some time).

Comment: Looks like a GCC bug. The standard allows it, and clang accepts it.

Comment: It's possible to provoke this with even simpler codes, e.g. https://gist.github.com/2220810 fails with `g++-4.7 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: @Philipp, Very interesting. So you don't even need the template parameters inside the braces for it to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like this is a GCC bug. Clang accepts it, and the standard allows it:

> *new-initializer:*
>
> > `(` *expression-list<sub>opt</sub>*`)`
> >     *braced-init-list*

And the rules for this initialization are not special:

> A *new-expression* that creates an object of type `T` initializes that
>   object as follows:
>
> — If the *new-initializer* is omitted, the object is
>   *default-initialized* (8.5); if no initialization is performed, the
>   object has indeterminate value.
>
> — Otherwise, the *new-initializer* is
>   interpreted according to the initialization rules of 8.5 for *direct-initialization*.

Comment: gcc-4.5.1 when compiled in C++0x mode (IDEOne) still has the error

Comment: More likely it is a bug in GCC : http://ideone.com/h7K7y .. I compiled it with gcc-4.6.1 `-std=c++0x`, which gave same error message.

Comment: `g++ -v` says that I am using `gcc version 4.6.3 (Debian 4.6.3-1)`. Also, `-std=c++11` is not recognised as a valid compiler option. I am in the process of testing `4.7`.

Comment: @Mat strange. I have 4.6.3 too (on Arch) and it works fine (if you use `-std=c++0x`, `-std=c++11` only exists from 4.7 onward). It also works for me in 4.7.

Comment: Ok, tested with 4.7 with similar result, error message having changed slightly. http://pastie.org/3679616 . I am using #! statler (64 bit). My 4.6.3 was up to date.

Comment: Oh, I feel so silly. I forgot to instantiate the template :S I'll delete my answer while I investigate further.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, I have reported this as a bug [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52742), linking back to this question. We'll see what the response is from that.