# new[size] object(args ... ) , GCC parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, gcc, initialization

I've a problem with my code that I don't realy understand.

I use «gcc version 4.7.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1)»

---

Edit : I use this line to compile

```
g++ -g -std=c++0x -o "GeneticEngine.o" -c "GeneticEngine.cpp"
```

---

Here is the Error I have:

```
GeneticEngine.tpl:16:5: erreur: parenthesized initializer in array new [-fpermissive]
```

And that is my (minimised) code:

---

GeneticEngine.hpp

```
#include "GeneticThread.hpp"

template <class T>
class GeneticEngine
{
    public:
        template <typename ... Args>
        GeneticEngine(int nb_threads,float taux_mut,int tranche_mut,std::string filename,int pop_size,Args& ... args);

        /* Other code */


    private:
        GeneticThread<T>* islands; /* Cause of error */

        int size;
};

#include "GeneticEngine.tpl"
```

GeneticEngine.tpl

```
template <class T>
template <typename ... Args>
GeneticEngine<T>::GeneticEngine(int nb_threads,float taux_mut,int tranche_mut,std::string filename,int pop_size,Args& ... args) : size(nb_threads)
{
/*next line is 16 : Error */
 islands = new  GeneticThread<T>[size](taux_mut,tranche_mut,filename,pop_size/nb_threads,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
};
```

---

GeneticThread.hpp

```
template <class T>
class GeneticThread
{
    public:
        template <typename ... Args>
        GeneticThread(float taux_mut,int tranche_mut,std::string filename,int pop_size,Args& ... args)
        { /* code ... */ };
     /* Other code */
};
```

---

I have read this ([Initializing arrays when using templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894406/initializing-arrays-when-using-templates)) but it's not exactly the same.

If you have a idea to fix it without having: [finaly I use this :/ ]

```
GeneticThread<T>** islands;
islands = new  GeneticThread<T>*[size];
for(int i=0;i<size;++i)
   islands[i] = new GeneticThread<T>(taux_mut,tranche_mut,filename,pop_size/nb_threads,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

---

I want to have:

```
 GeneticThread<T>* islands;
```

Is there a way to do it???

I try:

```
islands = new  (GeneticThread<T>[size](taux_mut,tranche_mut,filename,pop_size/nb_threads,std::forward<Args>(args)...));
```

and

```
 islands = new  GeneticThread<T>(taux_mut,tranche_mut,filename,pop_size/nb_threads,std::forward<Args>(args)...)[size];
```

But it not work.

---

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a non-default constructor for `new`ly allocated arrays.

Instead of using `new` like this, just use `vector` and pass in a properly constructed object to the `vector` constructor! Even if you never need to resize, `vector` will make sure that your memory is managed properly and not leaked.

For example:

```
std::vector<GeneticThread<T>*> islands;
```

Then:

```
GeneticEngine<T>::GeneticEngine(int nb_threads,float taux_mut,int tranche_mut,std::string filename,int pop_size,Args& ... args)
: size(nb_threads), islands(size, GeneticThread<T>(taux_mut,tranche_mut,filename,pop_size/nb_threads,std::forward<Args>(args)...))
{
};
```

Comment: I think to do this, but "islands" is a arry that never change (size). So vector are not the best to do this right?

Comment: I thought we could use custom constructor with new. Finaly i use «GeneticThread<T>** islands;». But thanks for your help.

Comment: @Krozark Vectors are appropriate even if you don't need resizing.